# How to functionally test dependent Grails applications

Tags: grails, testing

I am currently working on a distributed system consisting of two Grails apps (`3.x`), let's call them A and B, where A depends on B. For my functional tests I am wondering: How can I automatically start B when I am running the test suite of A?  I am thinking about something like JUnit rules, but I could not find any docs on how to programmatically start/manage Grails apps.

As a side note, for nice and clean IDE integration I do *not* want to launch B as part of my build `test` phase, but as part of my test suite setup.

Comment: Is this just something you want to happen in CI? Could you perhaps just write a shell script that fires up B followed by A?

Comment: As I said, I do not want this to happen in the build but as part of the test itself. I did this in Jersey before, where I would have a JUnit rule that would start B before the tests and stop it afterwards. Now I am looking for something similar in Grails. This makes functional testing from within the IDE a lot simpler.

Comment: No thoughts? I figured such a question would pop up sooner or later with the advent of microservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of months later and more deeply in the topic of Microservices I would suggest not to consider system tests as candidates for one single project - while I would still keep my unit- and service-level tests (i.e. API testing with mocked collaborators) in one project with the affected service, I would probably spin up a system landscape via gradle and docker and then run an end-to-end test suite in the form of UI tests.